# Data not transferring to a new activity

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, data-transfer

What am I doing wrong? I cannot get my data to transfer from where I click it on the list to the detailed view activity that the click opens.

Here is my code at the button click... and the data is available here due to the fact that the list shows the items.

```
            RecipeRepo repo = new RecipeRepo(this);

        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> recipeList = repo.getRecipeList();
        if(recipeList.size()!=0) {
            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);//getListView();
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                    recipe_Id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_Id);
                    String recipeId = recipe_Id.getText().toString();
                    Intent objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RecipeDetail.class);
                    objIndent.putExtra("recipe_Id", Integer.parseInt( recipeId));
                    startActivity(objIndent);
                }
            });
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( SousChef.this,recipeList, R.layout.view_recipe_entry, new String[] { "id","name"}, new int[] {R.id.recipe_Id, R.id.recipe_list_name});
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No recipe!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Like I said, I'm the data is available at this point because the listview shows the ID and the Name of each item.

After I click it using the following code... the activity is blank, and the toast in the item below comes up ID 0

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe_detail);

    btnEdit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.detail_edit);
    btnClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.detail_close);

    textName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.detail_recipe_name);
    textIngredients = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.detail_recipe_ingredients);
    textInstruct = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.detail_recipe_instruct);
    textCookTemp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.detail_cook_temp);
    textCookTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.detail_recipe_cooktime);
    textServes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.detail_recipe_servings);

    btnEdit.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnClose.setOnClickListener(this);

    _Recipe_Id =0;
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    _Recipe_Id = intent.getIntExtra("recipe_Id", 0);
    RecipeRepo repo = new RecipeRepo(this);
    Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
    recipe = repo.getRecipeById(_Recipe_Id);

    textName.setText(recipe.name);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Recipe id is " + recipe.recipe_Id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    textIngredients.setText(recipe.ingredients);
    textInstruct.setText(recipe.instructions);
    textCookTemp.setText(recipe.cooktemp);
    textCookTime.setText(recipe.cooktime);
    textServes.setText(recipe.serves);
```

From everything I have read this should be working but I must be leaving something out.  Also I am not producing any errors in the logCat or anything.

Comment: After a little more research I found that _Recipe_Id is reading the correct number but it is not being transferred to recipe. thus it is giving my recipe.recipe_id a number 0. Ideas?

Comment: ok the problem was in my getRecipeById code a simple mistake on which column to read from... problem was fixed by changing it to the read from the ID column

Comment: If the problem is solved you can add your own answer and accept it.

Comment: well I can accept it in a couple days lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word of advise... always make sure you mark the correct columns in your database... A simple mistake can cause you 2 days worth of work to go out the window.  In this case I had the getRecipeByID code looking for the column category instead of the column recipe_Id.   simple fix but could have been avoided.